# Python: Assign multiple values at once: pass all argv arguments to a function

Tags: python, arguments, tuples, argv

I want to pass all argv arguments to a function. I have created this code, but it gives me an error. How knows how to make this work? Many thanks for your help.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    createP(sys.argv[1:])

def createP( a, b, c):
    print a + b + c
```

I am running this app using the commandline:

```
python filename.py d e f
```

Returning:

```
NameError: name 'createP' is not defined
```

Comment: What happens if you define your function before the if statement?

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `createP` before you define it.  You're also passing the wrong number of arguments to it; you need to expand the array:

```
def createP( a, b, c):
    print a + b + c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    createP(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the order between the definition and the `if`.

Comment: Yes. The function needs to be defined first before I can call it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must inverse the order, as already said.
And to display variable lengths of **argv**, you should write:

```
def createP(*x):
    print '\n'.join(x)
    # or ' '.join(x) if you prefer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    createP(*sys.argv[1:])
```

I suppose that all elements of **sys.argv** are strings. Am I right ?

### Update

Well, my answer is a bit stupid; why the following code (without * for passing arguments and for definition of parameters) wouldn't be convenient ? :

```
def createP(x):
    print '\n'.join(x)
    # or ' '.join(x) if you prefer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    createP(sys.argv[1:])
```